# Visualize 7 million edges in pygraphistry

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, graph, edge-list

I have large dataset with of about 7 million edges and after an extensive search for methods and tool to visualise this data I came across `pygraphistry` I am trying to visualize the edges and connection without applying any modeling for now. But this has shows no errors no output for over 6 hours

My working environment is python 3.x anaconda and windows 64 bit

```
    import pandas
    import graphistry

    #  "GRAPHISTRY_API_KEY".
    graphistry.register(key='key_from_team')

    column_names = ['node1', 'node2', 'StartTime', 'EndTime']
    logs = pandas.read_csv('Edges.dat', header = None, names = column_names )
    logs[:4] # Show the first three rows of the loaded dataframe

    '''
    logs['StartTime'] = pandas.to_datetime(logs['StartTime'], unit='s')
    logs['EndTime'] = pandas.to_datetime(logs['EndTime'], unit='s')
    logs[:4]
    '''

plotter = graphistry.bind(source='node1', destination='node2')
    plotter.plot(logs)
```

Comment: Have you tried your code with a small number of edges? Does it work?

Comment: No same no error no output..